# NHibernate many to many mapping join by custom columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables Counter and Group that I want to link with an intermediate Counter_To_Group table.

```
Counter [Id, Version, PackageId, ...]
Group [Id, ...]
Counter_To_Group [Counter_Id, Counter_Version, Counter_PackageId, Group_Id]
```

Inside Counter object I want to have list of Groups:

```
public IEnumerable<Group> Groups {get; set;}
```

How can I map it with the Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have additional properties on the relation, you need a specific entity (or a component) in your business model to represent them.

```
Counter -(one-to-many)-> CounterToGroup -(many-to-one)-> Group
```

The CounterToGroup may be a component (it is called composite-element in XML mapping). It advantage of the component is that it has no identity and doesn't have to be explicitly added/removed from the database. It cannot exist without its parent. (On the other hand it cannot be shared between different instances of Counter, but this is something you most probably do not want.)

Comment: Is there no way to have it without this additional entity? Does it mean that I need to create/update this additional entity manually in the code when I want to assign counter to specific group? I would rather have such code: counter1.Groups.Add(group1) instead of counter1.Groups.Add(new CounterToGroup { Counter = counter1, Group = group1})

Comment: You can / should use a component.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup composite keys properly in your mappings, you can do it as follows,

```
HasManyToMany<Group>(x => x.Groups)
    .Table("Counter_To_Group") 
    .ParentKeyColumns.Add("Counter_Id", "Counter_Version", "Counter_PackageId") 
    .ChildKeyColumn("Group_Id")
```